# Compounding interest with monthly deposits using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, math

I'm very new to programming and have been set a task to write a simple function (as opposed to just printing each month's formula) that takes a deposit and number of months and returns the compounding interest after 6 months, with a fresh deposit of the same amount every month.

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
Initial and monthly deposit is $100

Monthly interest rate is 0.00417 (0.05 annually)
```

For my own purposes I've written out the formula:

```
# month1 = 100 * (1.0 + 0.00417)
# month2 = 100 + month1 * (1.0 + 0.00417)
# month3 = 100 + month2 * (1.0 + 0.00417)
# month4 = 100 + month3 * (1.0 + 0.00417)
# month5 = 100 + month4 * (1.0 + 0.00417)
# month6 = 100 + month5 * (1.0 + 0.00417)
```

And an attempt to turn it into a program:

```
def compound_interest(deposit, n):
    # n is number of months
    first_month = deposit * (1.0 + 0.00417)
    next_month = deposit + first_month * (1.0 + 0.00417)
    for i in range(n):
        first_month += next_month
        return i * deposit + first_month


print(compound_interest(100, 6))
```

Needless to say I think I'm barking up the wrong tree a bit here - I can't reconcile the maths with the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
def compInterest(periods, amount, rate):
    return amount*((1 + rate)**periods)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't take in to account the user making a deposit every month and as such the difference in interest per month - have edited the post to make that clearer